# To Grey Out the WHOLE Website when you click button inside Iframe contained in that website

Tags: javascript, html, css, iframe, web

I know how to grey out (adding grey color) to the whole website by a click of a button using css .

But here is an interesting scenario. I have a small IFrame embedded in the main website. Inside the Iframe I have a button. On-click the button I need to grey out the entire website. Currently I am only able to grey out the IFrame contents and not the entire website. If somebody can help me regarding this that would be great.

IFrame contents are on the same domain as the website but on different paths. For example if the website is xyz.com, the iframe contents displayed on that website are in xyz.com/cms.

Note: I only have access to the code sitting inside IFrame and not the outside bit. Hence I cannot code outside IFrame. Whatever I need to code I have to do it inside the IFrame.

Can't we do anything to window object to grey out the entire window?

Comment: Unless the iframe is on the same domain as the site you are trying to affect, I don't think this is possible

Comment: The iframe will be within the DOM... certainly you can roll up the DOM to find the "document"

Comment: IFrame contents are on the same domain as the website but on different paths. For example if the website is xyz.com, the iframe contents displayed on that website are in xyz.com/cms.

Comment: Can't we do anything to window object to grey out the entire window? I only have access to the code sitting inside IFrame and not the outside bit. Hence I cannot code outside IFrame. Whatever I need to code I have to do it inside the IFrame.

Answer (score 0):

I think setting the grey to when the iframe window has focus may work for you.

You didn't include any code so not sure if you're using jQuery, but try something like this.

```
while($(iframe).focus()){
   $('document').addClass('grey-out');
}
```

Comment: I only have access to the code sitting inside IFrame and not the outside bit. Hence I cannot code outside IFrame. Whatever I need to code I have to do it inside the IFrame.

Comment: The scenario should occur only when you click the button inside IFrame.